# Submatrix / vector contingent on values in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, submatrix

I have a 3D matrix `A` of size 20x500x68. I have two vectors carrying information regarding this matrix which are: 

`B` (containing zeros and ones) of size 1x68  and 

`C` (containing numbers from 1 to 3) of size 1x68

(in length both `B` and `C` correspond to the third dimension of `A`).

I would like to create a "sub matrix" of `A` only of that third dimension where `B==1` and `C==3`.

**Schematically:**

```
[sub matrix of A] = A (B = 1, C = 3)
```

Is there any way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SMA = A(:,:,B==1 & C==3)
%This submatrix contains all rows and columns of that third dimension of A
%where B equals 1 and C equals 3
```